# create a view programmatically with frame set to superview's frame?

Tags: iphone, frame, superview

I have a navigation based application where I place my custom views in the navigation view.

First, I wanna know how to get the "navigation view"'s frame so that I can place my custom view on it properly.
Also, I sometimes hide navigation bar and want to make sure I get the frame info correctly. (not with [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] )

Second, in general, how do I access the superview's frame so that I can place a view accordingly?
I tried the following with no success.

```
-(void) loadView {
[super loadView];
UIView* myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
self.view = myView;
self.view.frame = self.view.superview.frame;
[myView release];
}
```

or setting the frame in layoutSubviews, but noticed layoutSubviews not getting called. I guess that's because I don't have any subviews in this particular view?

Thank you

-Edit-

with given answers, i now know that i need to set the view.frame to superview's bounds.
The problem is that i'm unable to access superview inside viewDidLoad.
I can see that superview is correctly set in viewWillAppear but not in viewDidLoad.

I found out that viewDidLoad gets called at various times, such as when pushed by pushViewController or accessing self.view
I have the following code and viewDidLoad gets called from nil == controller.view.superview.

```
if (nil == controller.view.superview) {
    CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    controller.view.frame = frame;
    [scrollView addSubview:controller.view];
}
```

Since I can't access superview from viewDidLoad, i can't layout the view as i previously did in viewDidLoad. This seems so inconvenient and unnecessarily complex.
Any suggestion please?

Comment: you need to read view hierarchy in iOS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `superview` property is nil until your view is added as a subview somewhere.  In general, you can't know what the superview will be within the `loadView` method.

You could use autoresizing properties, as suggested by Costique.  Check out the *Resizing Subviews* in [the official UIView docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html).

You could also set the frame after the call to `loadView`, for example in something like this:

```
MyViewController *myController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
myController.view.frame = window.bounds;
[window addSubview:myController.view];
```

By the way, it is generally safer to use the parent's `bounds` property for the frame of the subview.  This is because a parent's bounds are in the same coordinate system as the subview's frame, but the parent's frame may be different.  For example:

```
UIView *parentView = /* set up this view */;
UIView *subView = /* set up subview */;
[parentView addSubview:subView];
parentView.frame = CGRectMake(30, 50, 10, 10);
subView.frame = subView.superview.frame;  // BAD!!!
// Right now subView's offset is (30, 50) within parentView.
subView.frame = subView.superview.bounds;  // Better.
// Now subView is in the same position/size as its parent.
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought I could do self.view.frame = self.view.superview.bounds; in my viewDidLoad(). But I noticed I am creating my view inside loadView but I haven't actually done anything to add it to superview via addSubview or anything. So the code doesn't do anything. Weird, I was able to see the view without adding it to parent view previously. How do I add my view (which was created in loadView) to parent view?

Comment: sorry I messed up reading my own code. I guess it was added when doing initWithRootViewController of UINavigationController

Answer (score 7):

Just set the autoresizing mask and the navigation controller will do the rest:

```
myView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Comment: ah thanks, it would work normally I guess. But I have a scroll view as one of myView. setting autoresizingMask to scrollview would not work I suppose?

Comment: Why not? UIScrollView is just a specialized UIView which manipulates its bounds origin for scrolling. The only thing I do differently is that I initialize UIViews with [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame rather than CGRectZero, but I don't think it matters at all.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion. but in my viewDidLoad(), [self.view bounds] (to layout subviews) returns (0,0,0,0). did I mess up somewhere? Do you get correct [self.view bounds] inside viewDidLoad?

Comment: If I recall correctly, viewDidLoad is sent before the view is added to the navigation controller's view hierarchy, immediately after loadView. It should be added to a superview by the time viewDidAppear: is sent. So if you need to calculate some geometry, Apple suggests you set the initial view frame to [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame. And by the way, you shouldn't send [super loadView] if you set the view property.